# Bugs with FB comments - backlinks (on the FB wall) doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have site, with articles with FB comments and share button plugins.
Share button works fine, but FB comments doesn't.
When I am on the site and type a comment and post it to the FB wall, the backlink to the article to the site doesnt work and I see this message :
"Unfortunately can not check details Comments, because of incomplete settings." 
I don't know where I am wrong, because the comments works fine here [here works](http://highlight-singing.com/events.php)

, but does not work here:
[does not working](http://highlight-singing.com/news.php)
I just don't know why. I make same things in this 2 pages.
Yes, there is multiple comments on the same page, but each article has different page with different GET variable, for the example:
highlight-singing.com/news.php?fb_share=537d1ab7458f0

Some help, please ?

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problem but you could try removing the www. from the link in the comment box and just use http://--- ?

Comment: When you see the comment on total wall, it works fine, but when you click on your FB profile, your personal wall the link doesnt work.

Comment: I also see you are using version 2.0 of FB JavaScript SDK, try removing "&version=v2.0" and see if it helps.

Comment: Same :(. Im just searching on the net, but cannot find the solution.

Comment: Not that it should cause your problem but I see the code to the comment's plugin is split into 2 lines :/ you could also try copying and pasting the comment's code from your events.php into your news.php and see what happens, replacing the URL of course.

Comment: Same :(. Just on the events page is not version 2, but on news page it is. With event page variant, same error.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SDK version and comments plugin on the new page to the same as the events page? If that fails then it could be a bug on FB side of things.

Comment: Yes I do, but same :(